# What is virtual tunnel interface "tunl0"?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking

My routing table looks as below:

```
[root@master ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.189.64  172.31.23.103   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
192.168.219.64  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.235.128 172.31.21.191   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
[root@master ~]#
```

I need help to understand output of the below command:

```
[root@master ~]# ip route get 192.168.235.131
192.168.235.131 via 172.31.21.191 dev tunl0 src 192.168.219.64
    cache
[root@master ~]#
```

Here, I understand that in order to go to `192.168.235.131`, the next hop is `172.31.21.191` based upon the routing table.

However, what do we mean by `dev tunl0 src 192.168.219.64?`

What is `virtual tunnel interface "tunl0"?`

Answer (score 1):

A `tunl<N>` interface is generally one used by the kernel's IP-in-IP encapsulation support. This is sometimes used to implement overlay networks -- e.g, in [Calico](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/about/about-calico), which can be used with both Kubernetes and Docker (and it looks like you're running Docker).